# Different urls on same website being served by different apps?

Tags: web-applications

Suppose there is a website www.xyz.com, is it possible to serve www.xyz.com/firstapp/* from one application(say a rails app) while serving www.xyz.com/secondapp/* from another application(a nodejs app)?

Comment: I see no reason why not.

Answer (score 0):

A [reverse proxy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) can accomplish this.
e.g using [NGINX](http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/)

```
location /firstapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://rubyonrails.org/documentation/;
}

location /secondapp/{
    proxy_pass http://nodejs.org/documentation/;
}
```